# ReduxForm data initial on Load of Form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

Using redux I created a form and I am able to dispatch actions, validations and is working fine without any issues. But load data/initialize on to form field(ReduxForm) not populating data but code executed, can anyone help me in fixing the issues or where I am going wrong, code executed fine but the data not populating on the respective form fields

```
import "../../views/CSS/Organization.css";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import {createOrganization} from "../../store/actions/org_actions"
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import moment from 'moment'
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'


class Organization extends Component {



        componentDidMount(){

        }


renderInputField = (field)=>(
    <div class='form-group' >
        <div class='oddT-icon-input' >
            <input {...field.input}  placeholder={`${field.placeHolder}`} class='oddT-text' />
            <i class={`${field.icon}`}></i>
        </div>
        <div class="validation-error">{field.meta.touched?field.meta.error:""}</div>
    </div>
  )




  render() {

    return (


<div>
        <Row>
                        <div class='col-sm-6' >
                        <label htmlFor="fePassword">Organization Name</label>
                            <Field 
                                name="orgName"
                                component={this.renderInputField}
                                placeHolder="Organization Name"
                                icon="fa fa-user"
                            />
                        </div>

    </Row>
);

}
}

function mapStateToProps(state,props){
    console.log(state)
    return {
        success: {orgName:"ARSCCOM"},
        initialValues :{orgName:"ARSCCOM"}
    }
}


export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'Organization',
    enableReinitialize : true

  })(connect(mapStateToProps,{createOrganization})(Organization))
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Does `Organization` component receive the updated value as `prop` in its `Field` component ?